# Binding ObservableCollection to ListBox via ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, observablecollection, listboxitem

I'm trying to use an ObservableCollection in conjunction with a ListBox, so that the ListBox is automatically updated when I add an element to the ObservableCollection, like so;

```
panels = new ObservableCollection<PanelCanvas>();
PanelList.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
PanelList.ItemsSource = panels;
```

This was working perfectly, but I had a ListBoxItem.Selected event that I really needed which I now can't use, as my ListBox is now populated with PanelCanvas objects rather than ListBoxItem objects.

So I've got the two approaches - ObservableCollection attached to the ListBox, which gives me automatic addition / removal events from the ListBox when an item is deleted from panels, and the approach of manually adding items via creating new ListBoxItem objects and putting them into the ListBox. This method means that I can use the ListBoxItem.Selected event!

What I'd really like is a method to combine the two - so the ListBox is populated automatically by the ObservableCollection, but rather than the ListBox being populated with PanelCanvas objects it's populated with ListBoxItem objects. Is this possible?

Edit: I did some digging around and found that I could use ListBox's SelectionChanged event and the SelectedItem property to get me satisfactorily similar behaviour. I'd still really appreciate any other responses!

Comment: You usually don't bind a ListBox's ItemsSource to a collection of UIElements (as "PanelCanvas"  suggests). There should instead be an ItemTemplate that uses the PanelCanvas element.

Comment: @mm8 I wrote the class, it inherits Canvas, which inherits UIElement :)

Comment: @LeoPoulson: Ok. You could hook up an event handler as I explained in my answer then. Or handle the SelectionChanged  event. Or bind the SelectedItem property.

Comment: @mm8 yeah handing the SelectionChanged event seems like the most suitable thing for me to do. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could programmatically add an event handler for the `ListBoxItem.SelectedEvent` event like this:

```
panels = new ObservableCollection<PanelCanvas>();
PanelList.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
PanelList.ItemsSource = panels;
PanelList.AddHandler(ListBoxItem.SelectedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ListBox_Selected), true);
```

...where `ListBox_Selected` is your event handler:

```
private void ListBox_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem item = e.OriginalSource as ListBoxItem;
    PanelCanvas panelCanvas = item.DataContext as PanelCanvas;
    //...
}
```

Or you could just bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox` to a `PanelCanvas` object of your view model if you have any.

Or handle the `SelectionChanged` event.